Representation of the dual of $C_0(\mathbb{N})$
Let define
$$ C_0(\mathbb{N}) = \{ f \in l^\infty(\mathbb{N}) | \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n =0\}.$$
I should prove that $C_0(\mathbb{N})^* \cong l^1(\mathbb{N})$.
I tried defining an operator
$$ \Phi : l^1(\mathbb{N}) \to C_0(\mathbb{N})^* $$
$$ a \mapsto \Phi_a $$ with $\Phi_a(f)=\sum_n a_nf_n $.
I have already proved that such a $\Phi$ is a linear isometry, and what remains me to show is that it is surjective. Can someone please help me?

I’m considering $C_0(\mathbb{N})$ with the norm $|| f ||_\infty = sup_n|f_n|$

Let $\phi \in c_0^\ast$. Consider the sequence defined by $a_n = \phi(e_n)$.

Thank you @DavidGao, I’ve concluded my attempt yet and what you suggested me is exactly what I’ve done, so your answer is a precious check for me, so thank you once again:)

Pick any $\phi \in C_0(\mathbb{N})^*$, and define the sequence $a=(\phi(e_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are the canonical unitary vectors.
Let us show that $a\in l_1(\mathbb{N})$ and that $\phi = \phi_a$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $s_n = |\phi(e_n)|/\phi(e_n)$ if $\phi(e_n)\neq 0$ and $s_n=0$ otherwise. In fact, for any $j\in\mathbb{N}$, $|\phi(e_j)| = s_j\phi(e_j) = \phi(s_j e_j)$ and then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum_{j=0}^n |\phi(e_j)| = \phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^n s_j e_j\right) = \left|\phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^n s_j e_j\right)\right| \leq \|\phi\|\left\|\sum_{j=1}^k s_j e_j\right\|_{\infty} = \|\phi\|.$$
It proves that the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\phi(e_j)|$ converges, so that $a\in l_1(\mathbb{N})$. Now we have to prove that $\phi = \phi_a$, but it is clear that they agree in $C_{00}(\mathbb{N}) = \text{span}\{e_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. It is easy to check that $C_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{N})$ and then we are done.

Thank you for your answer, it’s very clear :)
